# Comparing time in a datetime object python

Tags: python, django, datetime, comparison

I am having a weird problem.

I am running a django app and in one of my models I have a method to compare the time that the user gives and the time that is stored in the model db

So, for debugging purposes, I do this.

`print self.start`
`print start`
`print self.start.time < start.time`

And the output is:

`2012-10-15 01:00:00+00:00`
`2012-10-22 01:01:00+00:00`
`False`

HOW IS THIS POSSIBLE?!?!?!

I tried this in the django shell and in the python cli! Both give me True! With the same values.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Post the body of your method and how you are calling it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.time` is a *method*, not a property.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.datetime(2012, 10, 15, 1, 0, 0)
>>> a.time
<built-in method time of datetime.datetime object at 0x10049f508>
>>> a.time()
datetime.time(1, 0)
```

Therefore, the correct code would be `if self.start.time() < start.time()`.

Comment: Anddd that is correct. Its weird that I dont have to put the brackets in the cli thing but I do have to in django webapps. I really need to read about python fundamentals.

Comment: Actually, you have to put the brackets in the CLI, too. If you got a correct result in `a.time < b.time` in the CLI, that would be a fluke. Python 2 allows you to "compare" method objects, but the result is essentially arbitrary. Python 3 forbids those comparisons since they don't make any sense.